# Does OpenAI and ChatGPT use Scikit Learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ai, gpt, chatbot

Scikit Learn is Python's go-to open source package for running common AI and machine learning algorithms. Does OpenAI and its product ChatGPT use or rely on Scikit Learn on its back-end at all? If not, what do they use?

Answer (score 6):

Based on the limited amount of code in [OpenAI's GitHub](https://github.com/openai/), one of the primary packages is PyTorch. There is a much smaller amount of scikit-learn code.

Since OpenAI has not released any code for ChatGPT, it is unknown which packages are used in that system.

Comment: How do they make their website or API access and run algorithms on PyTorch in real-time?

Comment: My guess is PyTorch's `model.eval()`

Comment: Please expand your answer with an example web implementation of `model.eval()`.